# Java Radio Button

Tags: java

I am new Java user, I am making a form right now, I've added 3 radio buttons in my form, i want to show an error that if user select three radio button then a message appear that: "please select only one button".

My Code is like

```
}
    else
    {
        Check1="";

    }
    if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()==true)
    {
        Check2="C++";

    }
    else
    {
        Check2="";
    }

  if(jRadioButton3.isSelected()==true)
  {
      Check3="C Sharp";

  }
  else
  {
      Check3="";
  }

  {
    if(jRadioButton1+jRadioButton2+jRadioButton3.isSelected()==false) 
    {
    jLabel6.show("please Select one option");
```

Answer (score 2):

By reading your error message you want to print, you probably only want to select 1 RadioButton out of the 3 at a time (Please select only one also includes that selecting 2 should generate an error).

Therefore the appropriate solution would probably be to use a ButtonGroup

Answer (score 1):

Go for Good coding statndard Use 
ButtonGroup Class : used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of buttons.

Adding radio buttons into the group will not allow user to select more than one radio button. therefore you'll get rid of checking how many radio buttons user has selected.

Sample Code for you :-

```
package demo;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;


public class radio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form radio
     */
    public radio() {
        initComponents();

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(jRadioButton1);
        bg.add(jRadioButton2);
        bg.add(jRadioButton3);

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jRadioButton1.setText("One");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("Two");

        jRadioButton3.setText("three");

        jButton1.setText("Ok");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(215, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton1)))
                .addGap(134, 134, 134))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(radio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(radio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(radio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(radio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new radio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Hope this helps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining all three conditions like:

```
if (jRadioButton1.isSelected() && jRadioButton2.isSelected() && jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
    //user has selected all three buttons
}
```

Comment: This coding is working if i select all three button, if  i select 2 button it shows me same problem.

Comment: if that's the case you are looking for you should look for button group from which you could just select one button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet for your requirement

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"First radio Button selected");  
}  
elseif(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Second radio Button selected");  
}  
elseif(jRadioButton3.isSelected()){  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"third radio Button selected");  
}
elseif(jRadioButton1.isSelected()&& jRadioButton2.isSelected() && jRadioButton3.isSelected()){  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All 3 radio Buttons selected");  
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No radio Button selected");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer would be

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected() && jRadioButton2.isSelected() && jRadioButton3.isSelected)
  /*display message*/
```

However, you should be using check boxes. Radio buttons are for mutually exclusive items, meaning you can only chose one. Check boxes are for when there are a list of options, in which the user can chose any number of selections.